# Batch loop error - only 1 file is copied

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to run a bat file that:

1. creates a folder
2. searches for all files with `.log` extension
3. Copies and rename the files to `MyFile_customString.log` to another folder

So far I did this:

```
@echo off

set host_name=%1
set origin_path=%2
set destiny_path=%3
set destiny_host_path=%destiny_path%\%host_name%\
mkdir .\%destiny_host_path%

FOR %%G IN (%origin_path%/*.log) DO (
    SET _fileName=%%G
    SET _custom=%_fileName:.log=_%%host_name%.log%
    xcopy /Y /F %origin_path%\%_fileName% %destiny_host_path%\%_custom%
)
```

And having MyTest.log and MyTest2.log files in `origin_path` only MyTest2.log file is copied to `destiny_host_path`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at top of batch file after `@echo`

In your code:

```
FOR %%G IN (%origin_path%/*.log) DO (
    SET _fileName=%%G
    SET _custom=%_fileName:.log=_%%host_name%.log%
    xcopy /Y /F %origin_path%\%_fileName% %destiny_host_path%\%_custom%
)
```

should be:

```
FOR %%G IN (%origin_path%/*.log) DO (
    SET "_fileName=%%G"
    FOR %%H in (!host_name!) Do (
        SET "_custom=!_fileName:.log=_%%H.log!"
    )
    xcopy /Y /F !origin_path!\!_fileName! !destiny_host_path!\!_custom!
)
```

Comment: +1, probably 30% of the questions are related to the delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR %%G IN (%origin_path%\*.log) DO (
 xcopy /Y /F "%origin_path%\%%G" "%destiny_host_path%\%%~nG_%host_name%.log"
)
```

(untested)

No need for `delayedexpansion` in this case.

See `for /? |more` from the prompt for information on the use of `~`-modifiers to extract parts of filenames.

In your original, your `%`s were unbalanced (assuming that `%` had been correct in that context) in the `set _custom` line.

Tip: replace `xcopy` with `echo xcopy` temporarily to **show** rather than **execute** the command - easier to debug in case of an error...